# ":-( Something went wrong" message when trying to log in to hotmail/outlook on Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I'm trying to log in to my Hotmail account using Google Chrome web browser and after I enter my email and password, the page shows this in the center for about 10 seconds:

[image]

and then I get this message:

[image]

After that I'm stuck. If I close the web browser, re-open it and go to hotmail.com again, it goes back to the same screen as I showed above... so what now? I can't even log out.

Any idea how to add more screws to Microsoft to make it work?

Comment: As the error indicates, it appears that you're trying to access a database that no longer exists. Might be a problem with the redirect on Microsofts end? To log out, remove cookies in Chrome (`Ctrl+Shift+Del`) or try it in an incognito window (`Ctrl+Shift+N`) to attempt to login again. If this continues to fail, you're going to have to raise this with Microsoft/Hotmail. Looks like your account has something very wrong with it.

Comment: @AaronLayfield: It works if I log in via incognito mode. It also works w/o incognito if I log in to my other hotmail account, but then if I log out and try to log in to this one ... then this happens again. Same thing. It just started happening today.

Comment: Can you try clearing your full browser cache using the `Ctrl+Shift+Del` option? If it works in incognito mode, sounds like you've got a saved session/cookie that's left it in a broken state.

Comment: @AaronLayfield: To be honest with you I don't want to clear my cache. It will screw up all my other sites...

Comment: I know. But, unfortunately without a bunch of effort, there's no easy method of clearing cookies and sessions for a specific website.

Comment: If I remember correctly, on chrome you can click on the green padlock(https) (could look different, but should be at the start if the url) or something similar, apron clicking it it tells you what security is used on the webpage and other info, you can click on the second tab and there should be a section on the second tab where you can clear cookies from the website. Sorry if it isn't to clear as I don't have access to chrome at the very moment. Once the cookies are cleared for the specific website, try again and see if this error happens again

Comment: @Matt07211: Thanks, Matt. Clearing cookies just for that page did the trick ... so far, at least. Doing it like you showed keeps the rest of the cookies intact, which is a big plus!

Comment: Glad I could help